# camel: scan directories with antInclude

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I need to scan multiple directory's for PDF files, but I can't get it to work. I use a Blueprint XML in Servicemix 5.1.2. Here's a test route:

```
<route id="pdftransfer">
   <from uri="file://c:/Temp/out?antInclude=0*/*.pdf&amp;consumer.delay=60000&amp;move=save"/>
   <to uri="file://c:/Temp/in"/>
</route>
```

This is showing in the logfile

```
R​o​u​t​e​:​ ​p​d​f​t​r​a​n​s​f​e​r​ ​s​t​a​r​t​e​d​ ​a​n​d​ ​c​o​n​s​u​m​i​n​g​ ​f​r​o​m​:​ ​E​n​d​p​o​i​n​t​[​f​i​l​e​:​/​/​c​:​/​T​e​m​p​/​o​u​t​?​a​n​t​I​n​c​l​u​d​e​=​0​*​%​2​F​*​.​p​d​f​&​c​o​n​s​u​m​e​r​.​d​e​l​a​y​=​6​0​0​0​0​&​m​o​v​e​=​s​a​v​e​]
```

The files in underlying directories are not transfered.I played around with the antInclude configuration, but it will only transfer files when I point the file component directly to a directory, and do not use directories in the antInclude e.g

```
<from uri="file://c:/Temp/out/0123456?antInclude=*.pdf&amp;consumer.delay=60000&amp;move=save"/>
```

Also tried the ANT path matcher example described in the File Component documentation, with the same result.

How can I scan multiple directories with the file component?

Comment: Read more about ant style. I think you need to use **/*.pdf to indicate sub directories or something like that. But check Apache ANT for examples

Comment: The Ant pattern is pretty straightforward when I look at [Ant patterns](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html). I've tried serveral configurations with no result. I notice the logfile is not showing the antInclude config I defined. `antInclude=0*/*.pdf` is converted to `​a​n​t​I​n​c​l​u​d​e​=​0​*​%​2​F​*​.​p​d​f`, which is not a valid Ant pattern.

Comment: Use raw(xxx) or url encode - http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

Comment: Applied RAW, with no result. AntInclude works only for me when I scan a specified directory. Can't get subdirectories working.